Why are UTF-8 paths (differently) escaped in outputs across core CLI utilities?
Let's say that I'm a psychopath who names my files like:
  [-]   `{title: "Non-Metadata",    id: "s4a4ji"}`{.JSON5}.dir

That's my best attempt at making the most hideous plausible filename possible - it uses Pandoc Markdown and JSON5.
POSIX

If I enter this into ls, it provides me with a version which is escaped such that any POSIX-compliant shell (sh, of course, but also bash, in Fedora 40) shall be able to interpret it without issue:


ls "$PWD"



'  [-]'$'\t''`{title: "Non-Metadata",'$'\t''id: "s4a4ji"}`{.JSON5}.dir'



Octal

However, tree and file instead appear to replace non-ASCII characters with a kind of octet-escaped representation, which doesn't appear to be usable in the aforedescribed manner:


tree "$PWD"



.
└──   [-]\011`{title: "Non-Metadata",\011id: "s4a4ji"}`{.JSON5}.dir

2 directories, 0 files



UTF-8

And, of course, PowerShell Core's Get-ChildItem just outputs the full UTF-8 representation:


Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath "$PWD" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'Name'



  [-]   `{title: "Non-Metadata",        id: "s4a4ji"}`{.JSON5}.dir



How come these operate differently? I would expect ls, tree, and file to at least operate identically, considering that - to my knowledge - these are GNU CoreUtils. Additionally, PowerShell appears to demonstrate that nothing fundamentally forces these tools to escape non-ASCII characters, so why are they doing so?

Noteworthily, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46037095/function-to-escape-characters-in-paths/46037546#comment138781777_46037546 appears to be a potential solution to this, if using PowerShell.


POSIX

To the best of my knowledge, this was not POSIX syntax at the time your version of ls was released; the $'...' only became part of POSIX 2024 last week; until then it was just a widely adopted ksh syntax feature.

However, tree and file instead appear to replace non-ASCII characters with a kind of octet-escaped representation

This is octal representation, using a syntax that mimics C string literals. (Which do support hex, but octal is "traditional" in a way.) I think this is the style libbsd's strvis() uses by default.
Also, those are not "non-ASCII" characters: tabs are very much part of ASCII, which covers all byte values from 0 to 127. Byte values above 127 (0x7F, 0177) would be non-ASCII.

How come these operate differently?

They are three different programs, as simple as that. There is no common function to "output a file name" – each program applies whatever escaping it wants before writing it to stdout. (This is also where GNU and BSD styles differ.)

I would expect ls, tree, and file to at least operate identically, considering that - to my knowledge - these are GNU CoreUtils.

No they aren't. Only ls is GNU coreutils – the other two aren't even under the GNU umbrella at all.

Additionally, PowerShell appears to demonstrate that nothing fundamentally forces these tools to escape non-ASCII characters, so why are they doing so?

Programs can also do things without being "fundamentally forced" to do so. Many programs deliberately escape at least the ASCII C0 control characters so that they wouldn't be (mis)interpreted by terminals, for example.
Coreutils' ls has always had a selection of --quoting-styles with the intent of making 'invalid' characters easier to distinguish, and (as of version 9.0, if I remember correctly,) deliberately defaults to Bash-style quoting so that such file names could be directly copy/pasted into the GNU shell.
(See also the historical Unix dsw tool, and various other tricks people had to use to remove a file with an untypeable filename.)
PowerShell, on the other hand, doesn't even consider the string a file name: it's just a string-valued property of some object. When the entire object (the result of Get-ChildItem) is formatted to stdout, it applies some escaping, but the individual properties don't know anything about where they stand.
tree just makes a basic effort to prevent ASCII control characters from having undesirable effects to your terminal, but doesn't really aim for copypastability specifically.

I see - the binaries themselves are actually provided the exact string by the filesystem, but then generally apply escapes in order to not corrupt terminal output. Some, like ls, even go so far as to adapt their escaping to the current (or most popular) shell. That's superb. I suppose I better suggest this to PowerShell then, since it seems like a mistake to not do this for novice users of non-Latin languages. Many thanks for the verbose but clear explanations.
